# what function in Linux API implements execution of a script file with a shebang?

Tags: linux, exec, execvp, execv, execve

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/674

> ... the way shebang (#!) is typically implemented:
>
> 1. The kernel opens the executable, and finds that it starts with #!.
> 2. The kernel closes the executable and opens the interpreter instead.
> 3. The kernel inserts the path to the script to the argument list (as argv[1]), and executes the interpreter.

I was wondering what function in Linux API implements the above steps for execution of a script file with a shebang?

I have considered the following possibilities, but none of them seems a match:

- `execve()` will fail to execute a script.
- Either `execlp()` or `execvp()` seems to be just for executing a
  script without any shebang, default to be `/bin/sh`, according to
  APUE:

  > If either `execlp()` or `execvp()` ﬁnds an executable ﬁle using one of
  >   the path preﬁxes, but the ﬁle isn’t a machine executable that was
  >   generated by the link editor, the function assumes that the ﬁle is a
  >   shell script and tries to invoke `/bin/sh` with the ﬁlename as input to
  >   the shell.

  Can either `execlp()` or `execvp()` execute a script with a shebang
  for any language's interpreter (Python, Perl, Bash, ...).

Thanks.

Comment: I'm thinking [this might not be a bad place to start hunting](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/binfmt_script.c)...

Comment: Thanks. `load_script` seems to be used internally only, not a system call or a API function

Comment: Why do you think `execve()` fails? It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be implemented by `execve()`. All the other functions in the `exec` family are just wrappers around this (the ones ending with `p` perform the `$PATH` search to find the executable argument, the ones with `l` build the `argv` array by iterating through the variadic argument list).

It works the same for any language's interpreter -- the mechanism doesn't really care what the program in the shebang line does, it just executes it with the script pathname as an argument. You can even do:

```
#!/bin/cat
```

to create a file that just prints itself when you execute it.

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct that `execve()` can't execute a script without a shebang?

Comment: I believe that's true. Some shells will detect that error, and then try to execute the script themselves.

Comment: That's how script execution was originally implemented, before it was added to the kernel.